# Saxon indentatation in Java

Tags: java, xslt, saxon

I need to produce a well-indented XML file, through a transformer which supports XSLT 2.0.
I found that Saxon supports XSTL 2.0, but I cannot figure out how to produce an XML with a good indentation.

With the standard JAVA transformer, I used this code:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("myOutput.xml"));
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

which actually works well, but if I switch to Saxon with:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);
```

then the indentation does not work anymore. 
I also read the documentation and it seems that I would have to use the saxon:indent-spaces attribute, but it seems to available only in the PE version of Saxon. However, it says that the default value is 3, so it should be indented by default.

Anyway, do you know a way to produce a well-indented XML with Saxon (free version)?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of the input and output XML you're dealing with?  Does it have any indentation to start with, or any text nodes with leading or trailing whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me; to investigate, we'll need to see full details of the input and output, the Saxon version you are using, etc.

Incidentally, note that using a DOMSource with Saxon is up to ten times slower than using a StreamSource or SAXSource. Don't do it unless you need to build a DOM for some other compelling reason.

Comment: It seems that it was the xml:space="preserve" tag in the root. The interesting thing is that with the standard transformer the problem does not appear.

Comment: By "standard" I think you mean "non-standard". The standard explicitly says that if xml:space="preserve" is present in the tree, the serializer must not add or remove any whitespace.